# Does LinkedIn have a playground to test its API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I can't find a Playground or API Explorer to test the Linked In API. I've tried over the last 2 years or so and given up every time. Is there one?

Comment: The test account can be found there [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations#testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations#testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple answer is NO, there is no API explorer or playground.

**BUT** there is however a test company-account from linkedin you could use for the manage-company api calls.

```
Company Name : DevTestCo  
Company URL : https://www.linkedin.com/company/devtestco  
Company ID : 2414183
```

this account requires no oauth authentication and therefor api-calls can be easily tested.

Comment: Thanks. I was interested in just the Profile API and the Connections API, which do require OAuth, but I assume they do not need an organization or company account. Am aware of the test companies. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: unfortunatly they do need a partnership with linkedin. every application that needs the V2 api. needs to get a partnership

you can request a partnership for free but it takes a very long time to be accepted. we are currently waiting 2.5 months.

Comment: Oh, oh, oh! :-(

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working now :(

Comment: hi @Doug, linkedin has been taken over by microsoft, so old answers before 2020 will probably not work, as they decided to change their api.